# SAS connection to SQL Server DB using Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, sas

Can anyone give me the libname statement for making SAS to SQL Server connection using windows authentication or is it even possible without entering userid and password?

Thanks

Comment: What platform are you running SAS on?  Do you know what connection library SAS uses?

Comment: Which SAS engine are you using ? `OleDb`, `ODBC`, or `SQLSRV`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use a connection string that has `Trusted_Connection=True;`  How that property is communicated to the engine is dependent on the engine.

A great resource for all things connection strings is https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/